# Uniform convergence of a power series when avoiding a point of divergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Here's the exercise:

Let $\delta\in(0,1)$ and let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real, monotonic decreasing sequence that converges to $0$.
Show that $\sum a_nz^n$ converges uniformly on $\{|z|\leq1\}\cap\{|z-1|>\delta\}$

I quite frankly don't have any idea of how to approach this. Any hints and nudges in the correct direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes, exactly. sorry if that was phrased weirdly.

Comment: Thanks, I edited that in.  As for your problem, have you seen [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- Use the fact that $(a_n)$ is decreasing and converges to zero to show that there exists a positive and summable sequence $(b_n)_n$ such that $a_n=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{+\infty}b_k$ for every $n$.
- Use [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) to write $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant N}a_nz^n$ in terms of $(b_n)_{n\geqslant N}$ and $z$, for every $N$.
- Show that $\left|\frac{z^i-z^k}{1-z}\right|\leqslant\frac2\delta$ uniformly on $z$ in the domain you consider, for every $i$ and $k$.
- Deduce that $\left|\sum\limits_{n\geqslant N}a_nz^n\right|\leqslant\frac2\delta\,\sum\limits_{n\geqslant N}b_n$ for every $z$ in the domain you consider and for every $N$.
- Conclude.

Comment: Wow. That is amazing.